# Moodle: External user registration with web services

Tags: xml, service, moodle, registration

I'm trying to integrate Moodle with an external system, the main idea is that when a user is register to the external system it should be register in Moodle simultaneously.

In order to achieve this, I need to use web services on Moodle, specifically: *"auth_email_signup_user"*

I followed the instruction from the following Moodle document:
[Using web services](https://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Using_web_services.)

My idea is to use REST protocol and use the token of Admin user.

However, when I call the register service the Moodle server is returning me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<EXCEPTION class="moodle_exception">
    <ERRORCODE>registrationdisabled</ERRORCODE>
    <MESSAGE>Registration is disabled on this site</MESSAGE>
</EXCEPTION>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your moodle allow self registration? See https://docs.moodle.org/36/en/Reducing_spam_in_Moodle#Allowing_self-registration

Nevertheless, it would be much more secure writing your own plugin exposing a registration webservice. Also avoid using a admin token, create a custom user and role for this plugin

Comment: But activating Email-based-registration means that moodle sends users an email and I do not need that feature. Or that can be configured? Thanks!

Comment: Well the best idea for registering users in moodle is having an "auth plugin" anyways. Also in terms of handing cases like "user locking, deletion, ..." and so on... See for example https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Authentication_plugins. If your external system has a MYSQL DB with hashed (non-salted) you might try https://docs.moodle.org/36/en/External_database_authentication without any need for coding